# Remove driver installed by mistake

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers

Hope I am in the right place for such question.

I have a Xiaomi MI2 device and I connected it to my laptop (Windows 10) using USB cable.
It was on MTP mode but it wasn't recognised by windows. 
So I looked around for a solution and I found this guide: http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=218077&page=1#pid10327653

My initial state was a bit different than the one showed by the picture there (windows reconised that a MI2 device is connected but it still had that yellow triangle near it).

So I followed the guide but on **step 6** I didn't find `MTP USB device` but I did found something called `xiaomi accessories` so I installed it.

**WRONG :(**

After I installed this driver every time I connect my MI2 device via USB to my laptop the phone is going crazy - beeping and flashing.

How can I revert this??
I tried a system recovery for a weak ago but for some reason it failed :|

Thanks a lot guys.

---

UPDATE:

So I tried *Techie Gossip* answer but it didn't help.
See my message [here](https://xiaomi.eu/community/threads/mi2-usb-driver-installation.20371/#post-371195) with more information about the symptoms.

UPDATE 2:

Well I think I found some hack here.
I went to developer options and I turned on USB debugging.
Then I connected the phone again and it worked!
Now windows recognise it as an MTP device.
So weird.

Comment: It's really weird. If you turn off USB debugging mode again same issue..

Comment: Yes. Once usb debugging is turned off, the phone is going crazy again. What can be the reason for that?

Comment: did u try with other workstation or laptop.

Comment: Yes. I have another laptop (windows 7) and its state is the same as was with the current laptop before I messed it up. The phone is recognised under `other devices` with the label `MI2` and it has a yellow triangle with ! mark.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to uninstall Xiaomi related softwares and drivers.**

Make sure your phone in not plugged to PC

Go to control panel uninstall mi pc suite

Just delete the whole folder
C:/Program files/Xiaomi.

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER -------> Software----->delete the xiaomi folder.

Go to registry search for Xiaomi key word. Using find next option. Delete all the entries.

Go to Device Manager. In view option hidden device tick it up. You can see xiaomi related devices right click on that uninstall completely.

Delete Temp files.. restart your pc. Try to connect your phone let it install all drivers automatically.

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried but it didn't help - see my update to the first message.